# How can I start a service so that it keeps running even after app closes/killed in an Android app using React-Native/hybrid?

Tags: android, react-native

In an Android app developed using React-Native, how can I start a service/intentservice so that it keeps running even after the app closes or get killed. I tried HeadlessJS but as soon as the app closes everything stops. I know I can do this sort of thing with android native code using IntentService/JobIntentService but how can I achieve this using React-Native.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you can try [React Native Background Task](https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task),

sample use from the git page:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Text } from 'react-native'
import BackgroundTask from 'react-native-background-task'

BackgroundTask.define(() => {
  console.log('Hello from a background task')
  BackgroundTask.finish()
})

class MyApp extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    BackgroundTask.schedule()
  }

render() {
    return <Text>Hello world</Text>
  }
}
```

Comment: react-native-background-native limits the task every 15 minutes. I need to run it every 1 or 2 minutes.